# React native different package names for IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to have an Android package name com.android.app and IOs com.ios.app. The reason being they were two different code bases for the different platforms and they had different package names. Now that we have adopted React native how can I do it so that i don't loose my apple and play store information and maintain a single react native code base.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rename packages directly inside the ios and android folders the same way we do on native code